# How to capture a group and exclude a word in the capture?

Tags: regex

Example:
Book = string containing whole text

startChar = where it should begin capturing = `|`

endChar = where it should end capturing = `§`

word to ignore in capture = gray

So if it wasn't the word "gray", my capture would be a simple: `|(.+)§`

Here is an example of what i mean:

Book = "The gray fox is |so gray that its pretty gray§."

Captured = "so that its pretty "

Using C#, and PHP, but i do not want to use any replace function, i just want a pure regex expression.

Comment: Find the sentence using a regex, split on `/gr[ae]y/` and join the resulting pieces.

Comment: What tool or language are you using ?

Comment: Which language are you wanting to implement this in? Depending on that, you could also use a replace function, which in most languages accepts regex and placeholder/replacement sequences.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? For the above example what's your expected output? Does `Text = "` included in your input string?

Comment: Thing is, is that the sentence is a variable, so gray may appear anywhere in that sentence, all i have to define the capturing point is a starting character and an ending character. So if it wans't the word "gray", my catpture would be a simple: startChar1(.+)endChar1

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern in a global search:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\|)(?:\bgray\b)?\K((?:(?!\bgray\b)[^§])+)(?=(?:gray)?(§)?)
```

**[demo](http://regex101.com/r/qM4hW0/2)**

**details**

```
(?:                     # the two entry points
    \G(?!\A)            # position at the end of the pevious match
  |
    \|                  # the start
)
(?:\bgray\b)?           # optional "gray"
\K
((?:(?!\bgray\b)[^§])+) # all that is not the word "gray" (see the note)
(?=(?:gray)?(§)?)       # trick to capture the last §
```

**note**: this subpattern is a well know trick to match text avoiding a word. However, this subpattern is slow in particular with long text with few words to avoid.
It can be replaced with: `((?>[^g§]+|\Bg|g(?!ray\b))+)` that may be faster *(but less easy to build programmatically)*.

Example of use with PHP:

```
$book = "The gray fox is |so gray that its pretty gray§.";

$reg = '~(?:\G(?!\A)|\|)(?:\bgray\b)?\K((?:(?!\bgray\b)[^§])+)(?=(?:gray)?(§)?)~';

if ( preg_match_all($reg, $book, $matches) && !empty(end($matches[2])) )
    echo implode('', $matches[1]);
```

Note: the last capture group is only here to ensure that the end has been reached. The "if" condition checks it with `!empty(end($matches[2]))`

Comment: Thank you that complete answers my question.